# Editar documentos en una base de datos MongoDB uno por uno

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Intenté poner al dia mi base de datos cada elemento por cada elemento pero a pesar de utilizar `doc.update({'$set':` no persiste en la base de datos.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(
        f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    collection = client.test.sephora_backup3
    cursor = collection.find()
    for doc in cursor:
        attributes = get_benefits(doc)
        print("attributes: ", attributes)
        doc.update({'$set': {'attributes': attributes}}, upsert=False, multi=False)
    # product = [x for x in cursor]
    client.close()
```

¿He hecho algo mal?

```
>>> collection.find({"attributes": {$exists : true }})
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    collection.find({"attributes": {$exists : true }})
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## Actualizacion con `update_one`:

Intenté con la idea de los estimados Juan Rivera y JackNavaRow de cambia `update()` por `update_one()` pero parece que no funciona. Por seguro el problema esta el diccionario.

```
(sco_env) C:\Users\antoi\PycharmProjects\Bass\scoring\bass_scorer>python translate_to_english.py
  File "translate_to_english.py", line 106
    collection.update_one("_id": doc[id], {'$set': {'attributes': attributes}}, upsert=False)
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: No se deberia utilizar [update_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html)? Por otro lado, del error que pones, la estructura deberia ser "({key: value})"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como explica [@JuanRivera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/178674/juan-rivera) en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/442651/28035) para ***versiones superiores a 3.0 de MongoDB*** se debe trabajar con **update_one** , **find_one** y **update_many**

al trabajar con update_one los parametros son:

> update_one(filter, update, upsert=False,
> bypass_document_validation=False, collation=None, array_filters=None,
> hint=None, session=None)

El ***update_one***  se realiza desde la coleccion y tu lo estas ejecutando desde el registro, y por otro lado la busqueda por **`_id`** es por medio del ObjectId, asi que, para este ejemplo debemos importar la libreria ***ObjectId***

Con lo antes mencionado tu codigo debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
if __name__ == '__main__':
        client = pymongo.MongoClient(
            f"mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
        collection = client.test.sephora_backup3
        cursor = collection.find({"attributes":{"$exists":True}})
        for doc in cursor:
            attributes = get_benefits(doc)
            print("attributes: ", attributes)
            collection.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(doc['_id'])}, {'$set': {'attributes': attributes}}, upsert=False)
        # product = [x for x in cursor]
        client.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Segun la documentacion el metodo [`update`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) esta "**obsoleto**" por lo cual en vez de ello, estan estas funciones:

1. [update_one()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one)
2. [replace_one()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one)
3. [update_many()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many)

Y la primera es la que necesitas, sin el "`multi=false`", ya que `update_one()` solo toma estos parametros:

> update_one(filter, update, upsert=False, bypass_document_validation=False, collation=None, array_filters=None, hint=None, session=None)

Comment: Muchas gracias Juan, sin embargo, iterando sobre los docs del cursor, parece que un doc es un diccionario y no un documento...